# Converting Sql Query to Rails Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am having trouble in converting this query to Rails syntax. would any one please guide me

```
SELECT
   "users".*
FROM
   "affiliates"
INNER JOIN
   "users"
ON
   "users"."id" = "affiliates"."user_id"
WHERE (
   users.email ILIKE'%web%' or
   users.name ILIKE'%web%' or
   users.contact_number ILIKE'%web%'
)
LIMIT
   10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Rails way :

```
User.joins(:affiliates)
    .where("users.email ILIKE :name or users.name ILIKE :name or users.contact_number ILIKE :name", name: '%web%')
    .select("users.*")
    .limit(10)
```